# My webservice using apache shiro always return unauthorized

Tags: web-services, security, shiro, unauthorized

I have this shiro.ini:

```
[main]
ds = org.apache.shiro.jndi.JndiObjectFactory   
ds.requiredType = javax.sql.DataSource  
ds.resourceName = java:/comp/env/jdbc/myDS

# JDBC realm config  
jdbcRealm = org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm  
jdbcRealm.permissionsLookupEnabled = true 
jdbcRealm.authenticationQuery = "SELECT password FROM user WHERE username = ?"
jdbcRealm.dataSource = $ds


credentialsMatcher = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.Sha256CredentialsMatcher
# base64 encoding, not hex in this example:
credentialsMatcher.storedCredentialsHexEncoded = false
credentialsMatcher.hashIterations = 1024

jdbcRealm.credentialsMatcher = $credentialsMatcher

[urls]
/logout = logout
/** = authcBasic
```

Im debbuging JndiRealm in doGetAuthenticationInfo. I get an exception when shiro try to execute my authenticationQuery in getPasswordForUser method. Those are the lines that execute the select:

```
ps = conn.prepareStatement(authenticationQuery);
ps.setString(1, username);
```

My atuthenticationQuery is "SELECT password FROM user WHERE username = ?" so trying to access position 1 is invalid since it starts from position 0. Is that a bug on JndiRealm from apache shiro or i wrote my sql wrong?

Comment: You should use a debugger to see where the actual problem is. Is it in the custom method you have written? Are there any logs? There isn't much info to go on right now.

Comment: Nothing in the console :/. I debug my custom realm (http://picpaste.com/pics/Untitled-MUUmPu4U.1407350412.png) and i got something in return info;. I thought that if a SimpleAuthenticationInfo object is returned it means that the users is logged in.

Comment: My bad, the authenticationQuery cant have "".Working now.

Comment: Read the javadoc for setString:  "@param parameterIndex the first parameter is 1, the second is 2, ...". JDBC param counting always starts at 1, so there is nothing wrong with JdbcReam. If you have an exception, paste it.

Comment: Yes. I read it, my mistake, sorry. As i say i was using " in shiro.ini to sepcify my authenticationQuery and that was causing the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a simple mock implementation of a realm.

For logging in to work, you needs 2 steps:

1. authentication (is the username/password correct)
2. authorization (what is the user allowed to do)

Looks like you have only created the first step, but you are just giving back the password in the return statement.

Shiro will hash the password that was entered by the user. You should have the same hash stored somewhere in your database. In the doGetAuthenticationInfo you should do a lookup based on the username that was entered and retrieve the hash (either from the db, or disk or whatever you prefer), that is what you should put in the SimpleAuthenticationInfo object and return, shiro will do the user password hashing and comparison for you.

For the second step, override the method doGetAuthorizationInfo. You could let it return an instance of SimpleAuthorixationInfo containg a set of permissions, the simplest being "*", when it has access to everything.

Creating such a method can be as simple as:

```
@Override
public AuthorizationInfo doGetAuthorizationInfo(PrincipalCollection principals) {
    SimpleAuthorizationInfo info = new SimpleAuthorizationInfo();
    //here you can create custom permissions based on the principal 
    //that has been authenticated using your own logic
    info.addStringPermission("*");
    return info;
}
```

Comment: Tnks for the reply, can u tell me how do i add permissions to my subject? i read this documentation ( http://shiro.apache.org/java-authorization-guide.html ) but it doesnt say how. Also, i overrided the doGetAuthorizationInfo but when i debug the method is never called.

Comment: Added extra info on both steps

Comment: I follow ur tips and also follow this tutorial ( http://blog.pinateknoloji.com/shiro-jdbc-realm). Now my doGetAuthenticationInfo is reading the hashed password from the database that have the same value of the hashed value that i get within doGetAuthenticationInfo. I also added the selected password in my returned SimpleAuthenticationInfo but still no authorization. Im new to stackoverflow as a poster so i dont know where is the best place to paste my code since comments dont allow line breaks and have limited characters.

Comment: Just edit your original question. Or if it answers your own question post it as an answer

Comment: Eddited, just added the modifications that i made

Comment: Ok, i decided to use the JndiRealm shiro's implementation, that way deleted my JdbcRealmImpl and set shiro.ini to use JndiRealm. Im gonna update the post to tell whats going on.

Comment: You totally changed the question, only edit the question for additional information, if you have a new question, create a new one. Now my answer is totally off-topic.